# Design Decision: (EF & WCF) Chatty or Chunky?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity Framework (v4) entity with several multi-layered navigation properties included. It's potentially a very deep object. The resulting entity can be small, or pretty significant in size. It's never super-large; never megabytes of data or whatever.

Also, I am NOT trying to solve a problem with payload size or any error I am receiving. I am simply trying to determine which is the best solution for this type of situation.

Let's call my Entity Framework entity a Project record.

Is it smartest to build a WCF method like this:

```
public Project GetProject(int projectId) { }
```

Or like this:

```
public Project GetProject(int ProjectId) { }
public Project GetProjectPart1(int ProjectId) { }
public Project GetProjectPart2(int ProjectId) { }
public Project GetProjectPart3(int ProjectId) { }
public Project GetProjectPart4(int ProjectId) { }
```

I guess it's a question of Chunky versus Chatty.

Is this just an "it depends" sort of situation or is there a General Rule of Thumb in these design decisions? I've heard arguments for chatty and I have heard arguments for chunk. To be honest, they both seem to make sense; both with benefits and both with negatives.

Comment: I would like to cast my vote for Chatty. The reason it, Chunky is easier. And, I get paid by the hour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it could depend on the environment. If this is a public WCF method, then sending larger amounts of information over http could be problematic. However, in a local environment, you have other options.

Programatically, I would probably go for the chunky option, without the overhead of having to piece the project together with 4 seperate calls.

Decisions, decisions.

Answer (score 0):

To give a counter to Chris's answer:

A system I helped put together was an embedded system talking to a Windows server.  It would certainly have been possible to do things in a chunky way.  However, the embedded system was an access controller that read badges and opened (or not) doors based on the badge number's access levels.

If we'd done things in a chunky way, the configuration download would have taken the doors off-line for more than a minute.

Doing things in a chatty way meant that each individual "chat" could be handled without taking anything offline.  Sure, the overall download time was longer, but there was never any downtime.

To re-iterate: Decisions, decisions.

Comment: So, this rule of thumb is: If you don't have time for chunky and you only have time for the chatty, it makes sense to choose the chatty approach. ;) Got it.

Answer (score 0):

When I can't choose between two ways of doing something, it usually means both are in fact useful. So, as a compromise, in terms of pure API, I would define it this way:

```
public Project GetProjectPart(int ProjectId, int firstPartIndex, int lastPartIndex) { }
```

You can decide not to implement the handling of fistPartIndex & lastPartIndex in the initial phases of your project, but at least the API will be future proof, which I think is a very important part of the decision when I start defining public services.

Comment: Yes, but you are just pushing the decision choice off to the developer/consumer. That can be valid, but I was really looking for some overarching reason for one over the over. For example, are chunky calls more likely to fail? Are chatty calls too difficult to transact? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could go down a halfway-house route of having a couple of methods for your loading your Project entity depending on your requirements: -

```
LoadProjectLight(int projectId)
LoadProjectFull(int projectId)
```

The former would just load in the "top level" of the object graph i.e. the Project entity, and the latter which would load the full object, using .Include() to bring in the parts of the graph that are required.

You would use the Light method when you only need top-level depending e.g. master list of Projects, and then the Full method when you need the entire graph e.g. editing the object in a details view.